# Merge two variadic templates in one

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, typelist

Im trying to implement a variadic template wrapper of the loki typelist.

Merging two typelists in loki-style is easy, but im having problems with merge in variadic-template style.

This is my implementation (Simplified, without push_back , index_of , ... , methods).

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct dl32TypeList;

template<typename HEAD , typename... TAIL>
struct dl32TypeList<HEAD,TAIL...>
{
    static const unsigned int size = sizeof...(TAIL) + 1;

    using value = dl32Loki_like_TypeList<HEAD, typename dl32TypeList<TAIL...>::value>;
};

template<>
struct dl32TypeList<>
{
    using value = dl32NoType;

    static const unsignedint size = 0;
};
```

I want something like:

```
template<typename OTHER_TYPELIST> 
using merge = dl32TypeList<HEAD , TAIL... , typename OTHER_TYPELIST::???>;
```

And this is the problem: We cannot store variadic template args as a using/typedef, so i have any idea about how i can do this. (Note the OTHER_TYPELIST::???).

Comment: Could you provide a complete example? What is `dl32Loki_like_TypeList`, is it meant to be `dl32TypeList`? What is `dl32NoType`?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, the message is too short. dl32 is a prefix of my library types. dl32TypeList is the wrapper of the loki-style typelist (As described in Alexandrescu's "Modern C++ desing", dl32_loki_style_typelist is a implementation of that typelist). dl32NoType is a type without meaning, basically a mark for type operations. In this case, dl32NoType marks the end of the typelist.

Comment: @Manu343726 I don't really feel like researching this, but are you implementing a typelist from a **2001** book using **C++11**'s native type list facility? Is this purely an exercise? Translating a C++11 parameter pack into C++98 constructs and then adding a C++11 interface is just stupidly convoluted.

Comment: Yes, this sounds stupid. Its only a personal exercise to practice with C++11, and tmp.

Comment: Finally, i deprecated the loki-style typelist of my library, and use only the variadic template version instead. Variadic-template version is easier to implement (The operations, not only the list).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what Loki or DL32 are, and it's not clear you should be implementing anything at all.

`std::tuple` is a common tool for type lists. It is designed as a runtime storage container but works as a compile-time utility as long as the types are complete. Here is one way to catenate tuples:

```
template< typename ... t >
struct tuple_cat
    { typedef decltype( std::tuple_cat( std::declval< t >() ... ) ) type; };
```

If you want to do it manually, try partial specialization:

```
template< typename ... t >
struct type_list {};

template< typename ta, typename tb >
struct type_cat;

template< typename ... a, typename ... b >
struct type_cat< type_list< a ... >, type_list< b ... > >
    { typedef type_list< a ..., b ... > type; };
```

As for the `size` member, you can make a universal metafunction to solve the problem once and for all.

```
template< typename >
struct count_types;

template< template< typename ... > class t, typename ... a >
struct count_types< t< a ... > >
    { static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof ... a; };
```

Comment: Could you supply some code to show how this would be used please? Struggling with the syntax

Comment: @makar which one? Please ask a separate question. You may post a comment here with a link, but I can't guarantee I'll be the one to answer.